# Python and ElementTree: write() isn't working properly

Tags: python, elementtree

First question. If I screwed up somehow let me know.

Ok, what I need to do is the following. I'm trying to use Python to get some data from an API. The API sends it to me in XML. I'm trying to use ElementTree to parse it.

Now every time I request information from the API, it's different. I want to construct a list of all the data I get. I could use Python's lists, but since I want to save it to a file at the end I figured - why not use ElementTree for that too.

Start with an Element, lets call it ListE. Call the API, parse the XML, get the root Element from the ElementTree. Add the root Element as a subelement into ListE. Call the API again, and do it all over. At the end ListE should be an Element whose subelements are the results of each API call. And the end of everything just wrap ListE into an ElementTree in order to use the ElementTree write() function. Below is the code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "http://http://api.intrade.com/jsp/XML/MarketData/ContractBookXML.jsp?id=769355"

try:
    returnurl=urlopen(url)
except IOError:
    exit()

tree = ET.parse(returnurl)
root = tree.getroot()

print "root tag and attrib: ",root.tag, root.attrib

historyE = ET.Element('historical data')
historyE.append(root)
historyE.append(root)

historyET = ET.ElementTree(historyE)
historyET.write('output.xml',"UTF-8")
```

The program doesn't return any error. The problem is when I ask the browser to open it, it claims a syntax error. Opening the file with notepad here's what I find:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<historical data><ContractBookInfo lastUpdateTime="0">
   <contractInfo conID="769355" expiryPrice="100.0" expiryTime="1357334563000" state="S" vol="712" />
</ContractBookInfo><ContractBookInfo lastUpdateTime="0">
   <contractInfo conID="769355" expiryPrice="100.0" expiryTime="1357334563000" state="S" vol="712" />
</ContractBookInfo></historical data>
```

I think the reason for the syntax error is that there isn't a space or a return between 'historical data' and 'ContractBookInfo lastUpdateTime="0"'. Suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide the URL?

Comment: I edited the post to include the url. But I think it's not relevant. And the reason I think this is if I jump the whole "adding elements to another element then wrapping" thing, and instead try to write() the thing that I get from the url as is it [that is, just doing tree.write()] that works perfectly. So the problem is somewhere in adding each Element to the list of elements, or in the wrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
historyE = ET.Element('historical data')
```

You shouldn't use a space.  As summarized on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document):

> The element tags are case-sensitive; the beginning and end tags must
>   match exactly. Tag names cannot contain any of the characters
>   !"#$%&'()*+,/;<=>?@[]^`{|}~, nor a space character, and cannot start
>   with -, ., or a numeric digit.

See [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) of the XML spec for the details ("Almost all characters are permitted in names, except those which either are or reasonably could be used as delimiters.")

Comment: Indeed! Thank you kind Sir. I would've never solved it.

How do I check this question as solved?